# Is there a way to fix nix errors on replit?

Tags: python

I am using nix for the first time in python. But when I run the python script I get an error that I can't seem to fix. So I am wondering if there is anyway to fix this. here is the error:

```
Replit: Package operation failed.

nix error: building nix env: exit status 1
Output has been trimmed to the last 20 lines
evaluating file '/nix/store/bsvp85bibdc4fngcfvbvnc0dbb7ssbhi-nixpkgs-21.11-src/pkgs/top-level/config.nix'
evaluating file '/nix/store/bsvp85bibdc4fngcfvbvnc0dbb7ssbhi-nixpkgs-21.11-src/lib/options.nix'
evaluating file '/nix/store/bsvp85bibdc4fngcfvbvnc0dbb7ssbhi-nixpkgs-21.11-src/pkgs/stdenv/linux/default.nix'
evaluating file '/nix/store/bsvp85bibdc4fngcfvbvnc0dbb7ssbhi-nixpkgs-21.11-src/pkgs/top-level/stage.nix'
evaluating file '/nix/store/bsvp85bibdc4fngcfvbvnc0dbb7ssbhi-nixpkgs-21.11-src/pkgs/stdenv/adapters.nix'
evaluating file '/nix/store/bsvp85bibdc4fngcfvbvnc0dbb7ssbhi-nixpkgs-21.11-src/pkgs/build-support/trivial-builders.nix'
evaluating file '/nix/store/bsvp85bibdc4fngcfvbvnc0dbb7ssbhi-nixpkgs-21.11-src/pkgs/top-level/splice.nix'
evaluating file '/nix/store/bsvp85bibdc4fngcfvbvnc0dbb7ssbhi-nixpkgs-21.11-src/pkgs/top-level/all-packages.nix'
evaluating file '/nix/store/bsvp85bibdc4fngcfvbvnc0dbb7ssbhi-nixpkgs-21.11-src/pkgs/top-level/aliases.nix'
evaluating file '/nix/store/c1j7ydmmp8jb6gy4xq8vy9s8bgaj0hw7-nixpkgs-stable-21_11-21.11.tar.gz/nixpkgs-stable-21_11/overlay.nix'
evaluating file '/nix/store/bsvp85bibdc4fngcfvbvnc0dbb7ssbhi-nixpkgs-21.11-src/pkgs/stdenv/generic/default.nix'
evaluating file '/nix/store/bsvp85bibdc4fngcfvbvnc0dbb7ssbhi-nixpkgs-21.11-src/lib/customisation.nix'
evaluating file '/nix/store/bsvp85bibdc4fngcfvbvnc0dbb7ssbhi-nixpkgs-21.11-src/pkgs/tools/text/gawk/default.nix'
evaluating file '/nix/store/bsvp85bibdc4fngcfvbvnc0dbb7ssbhi-nixpkgs-21.11-src/pkgs/servers/x11/xorg/default.nix'
evaluating file '/nix/store/bsvp85bibdc4fngcfvbvnc0dbb7ssbhi-nixpkgs-21.11-src/pkgs/servers/x11/xorg/overrides.nix'
evaluating file '/nix/store/bsvp85bibdc4fngcfvbvnc0dbb7ssbhi-nixpkgs-21.11-src/pkgs/stdenv/generic/make-derivation.nix'
evaluating file '/nix/store/bsvp85bibdc4fngcfvbvnc0dbb7ssbhi-nixpkgs-21.11-src/pkgs/build-support/mkshell/default.nix'
evaluating file '/home/runner/using-nix/replit.nix'
error: syntax error, unexpected end of file, at /home/runner/using-nix/replit.nix:1:1

could not read stderr: /home/runner/using-nix/venv/bin/python3: line 3: exec: : not found
failed to run adapter: could not parse port from adapter: strconv.Atoi: parsing "": invalid syntax: EOF
```